# How to get file object for file created in execpath in Bazel?

Tags: bazel

I have a bash script:

```
mkdir a_dir
echo "Hello World!" > a_dir/out1.txt
echo "Hello World!" > a_dir/out2.txt
```

I would like to create an action to run the script, and have the files it creates declared as outputs, and be able to pass them as inputs to other actions.

The problem is I can't figure out how to reference the files weather with  `ctx.actions.declare_file` or some other method that I'm not aware of.

I think what I'm looking for is a method to get `File` objects that reference files under the `execroot` path.

Note: The actual binary I will be running instead of the bash script doesn't grant control over the path of its output, so declaring a file within the implementation function and passing it as a parameter to the binary is not an option.

Comment: Since outputs are expected rooted at a specific location, would it be an option to write a wrapper that does take those `outputs` arguments and after calling the tool in question copies / moves the results generated with those hard-coded paths to the declared output(s)?

Comment: I will respond to this in a the question answer I will post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking online and opening a thread on [bazel-discuss](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/bazel-discuss/pC6udirc5Q0), It seems like there isn't any way of declaring outputs outside of the output root.

The solution I chose is creating a wrapper script which `cd`s into the output directory, `out_dir`, which is evaluated as `paths.join(ctx.bin_dir.path, ctx.label.package)`

The reason I chose `cd` rather `mv` or `cp` is discussed in the bazel-discuss thread.

After `cd` into `out_dir`, the paths of files given to the binary as arguments are no longer valid, and can be fixed by prepending them with `..`s. If the files that are to be fixed are in a `depset` and you require to fix the paths without converting the `depset` to a list, you can prepend the path-fix using the `format_each` parameter of `args.add_all()`.

This is not the most elegant solution, but as far as I know, does not compromise functionality. Here is some example code:

```py
# Inside implementation function:
out_dir = paths.join(ctx.bin_dir.path, ctx.label.package)
path_fix = "/".join(len(out_dir.split("/"))*[".."])
args = ctx.actions.args()
args.add_all(files_depset, format_each=path_fix+"/%s")
ctx.actions.run_shell(..., command = "cd {out_dir}; {binary} $@".format(
    out_dir = out_dir,
    binary = your_binary
))
```